# Why curl response shows false?

Tags: php, curl

I am connecting to some websites from a list.txt with curl, searching for a word in the source,and saving each word in a text file. My problem is that I am seeing results only for the last website in the list.txt . How can I fix that ?

```
<?php

$text = file_get_contents('text.txt');    
$values = preg_split('/[\n,]+/', $text);

foreach ($values as $url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $content=curl_exec($ch);

    $html = strstr(htmlspecialchars($content),"data: { mailto:");
    $email = substr($html,22,30);

    $myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!"); 
    fwrite($myfile, $email);
    fwrite($myfile, "\r\n");
    fclose($myfile);
    curl_close($ch);
}

?>
```

Comment: What happens if you echo $email in the loop? Is it printed ok on screen?

Comment: What does `var_dump($values)` show?

Comment: echo $email shows only one result for the last url in the text.

Comment: var_dump($values) shows the array of items in the list

Comment: In that case it's not a problem with writing the file is it? You are not parsing the pages correctly. Your question is incorrectly written. Please update the question with relevant information regarding parsing the webpages instead.

Comment: I need to use htmlspecialchars and substr with the array . Thats the problem I think

Comment: Instead of `file_get_contents()` use [`file()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)